# Why does Cm -> Am sound good?

Tags: chord-progressions

To me it sounds quite dark and brooding, but also sounds like a resolution.

As far as I can tell, it doesn't really fit in to any modal scales. I guess it fits in an A blues scale, but it doesn't sound particularly bluesy to me.

Comment: Hope you get a good answer here.  Just want to point out that analysing chord progressions in terms of scales to work out why hings sound the way they do is almost always more misleading than useful.  In terms of harmony, at the very most, a certain scale can give you an interesting artificial limit with which to derive chord progressions, but nothing more.  Sometimes it's helpful to use scales to decide what notes to play over chords but the other way round not so much.

Comment: "Sound good" is almost always going to depend on context (Cm Am definitely would *not* sound good in a Gabrielli motet, for example). By the way, the harmonic motion A-C-Eb-F# (either minor or major, doesn't matter) is rooted in the nonatonic or enneatonic scale (which has nine tones instead of eight), and yes, it is dark and brooding and pretty awesome.

Comment: This isn't quite an answer to your question, but one of the interesting things about a Cm -> Am progression is the sense of *change*; so when writing a melody over that progression you shouldn't expect to use the same notes (same *scale* if you like) over both chords. You might for example choose to highlight this change using Eb to E (m3 of C to 5 of A), or using the b6 of the Cm (Ab) moving to the 1 of the Am (A).  Conversely, the note C itself when held or repeated sounds different as the chords change, this "recontextualising" of the same note is interesting to the ear (1 of C to m3 of A).

Comment: Your observation that it doesn't fit to a modal scale is an astute one: one of the interesting things about a Cm -> Am progression is the sense of change; when writing a melody over that progression you shouldn't expect to use the same notes over both chords. You might for example choose to highlight this change using Eb to E (m3 of C to 5 of A), or using the b6 of the Cm (Ab) moving to A.  The "space change" is sort of the point, Conversely, the note C itself when held or repeated sounds different as the chords change, this "recontextualising" of the same note is interesting to the ear.

Comment: Hollywood quite likes these "space change" chord changes. Another one is  C major -> Ab major - again the C is "recontextualised".  Less drastic is C major -> Db maj7 which is less cinematic and more sparkly and "open" sounding, often used as a deceptive ending thing

Comment: @Some_Guy: Your comments are starting to sound like an answer :)

Comment: @JohnWu: Yeah, I appreciate the context thing. My context when I came across this was just noodling on a piano. No other accompaniment, no other musical context. I suspect that it's something that I've come across in some suspense film I've seen, though I can't remember which. Feels very Stranger Things.

Comment: @Some_Guy: https://www.scales-chords.com/scalefinder.php is really useful for finding scales. But yeah, there are also no modal scales with Eb that also have C and E, so it kind of stuck out.

Comment: @JohnWu - the notes A C Eb F# constitute a fully diminished chord or arpeggio. As found in many 'suspense' music situations. All notes found in the usual way- R, m3, d5, d7. Why should it be thought of in any other way?

Comment: @naught101 - If a set of notes can't be found in a major or minor scale, it won't be found in a mode either, because modes are made up from those very same notes.

Comment: Am to Cm works well too, but not dark. 'Shadow of Your Smile'.

Comment: @Tim You're correct, when you arpeggiate *pitches* you get a dim7 *chord*. When you arpeggiate *chords* (either all major or all minor) at those intervals, you get one of those 9-tone *scales*. Just as the dim7 chord is completely invertable, the 9-tone scale is completely centerless. You can play those four chords pretty much in any order and avoid or create a sense of cadence anywhere, simply through rhythm. So it's great for creating a sense of the infinite. (It seems to work best when you use contrary stepwise motion in the outer voices.)

Comment: @JohnWu - so, starting, say, with C, what are the *9 tones*?

Comment: If you use this pentatonic scale over the C min scale, C-D-Eb-G-A, and then switch to the A min chord, then you can play the same scale and get a sort of A min blues sound.

Comment: @Tim Usually half-step whole-step, e.g. C Db Eb E F# G A Bb C. If you want to try something crazy, there is also the whole-step half-step scale (C D  Eb F F# Ab B C) but you'd have be a little more creative how to use it.

Comment: @JohnWu - generally called half/whole diminished, and whole/half diminished scales. There's an A missing from the whole/half. And they're *eight* note scales, not nine. The ninth is an octave copy of the root.

Comment: @Tim Oops you're right. Hey, why did you ask?

Comment: @JohnWu - it was the strange (perhaps inaccurate) names you gave it. Known about , and used the two dim scales for ages, but a scale with 9 tones/notes? Intrigued. That's why!

Comment: Octatonic scale is what I've always called it, and yeah it's cool, radiohead's *Just* springs to mind.  And while it's true that it might be useful to jam against this progression it's not true to say the progression is "rooted in" that scale.

Comment: @Neal: Yep, I think so. I never would have found that question, but I'm happy for this to be marked as a duplicate, especially since Pat's answer is almost identical on both..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason that a lot of people like this kind of progression is because it can be written with extremely smooth voice leading, and yet still has a “fresh” sound due to its inherent chromaticism. In other words, the chords are close enough to connect easily, but distant enough to have a harmonic spiciness. The relationship is referred to as a “chromatic mediant”.

There are four possible chromatic mediant related chords from any starting chord, and each has their own flavor.
The definition of a chromatic mediant relationship is that the two triads are 1) the same quality, and 2) have roots a third apart. In your example, 1) both triads are minor, and 2) the root of the second chord is a minor third below that of the first. Other chords with the same kind of relationship to Cm are Abm, Em and Ebm. Any two chords that are chromatic mediants of each other will have the same kinds of connections with each other:

1) There will be one common tone. In your example this is the C.

2) There will be one stepwise movement. In your example, that’s the G moving to A.

3) There will be one chromatic shift. In your example that’s the Eb becoming E.
If you check, you’ll see that these same relationships always apply so long as the qualities of the two triads stay the same, and the roots are a third apart.

Answer (score 2):

'Why does it *sound good*?' You're probably looking for a theoretical explanation. However, theoretical explanations don't necessarily 'make things sound good'.

It may sound good to you (and me!), but that in itself is a good reason. It just does! As mentioned in comments, though, in other contexts, it will sound anything but good.

For the theoretical explanation, the term *parallel key* comes into play. here, C major/C minor. Chords and harmonies from a major key mix quite well with those from the same root minor. Thus, Am is part of the diatonic chord system in C maj., and obviously part of the diatonic chord system in C min.

However, another explanation is that it's a chromatic mediant. Two chords (either both maj. or both min.) which have their roots a third apart. That third can be major or minor in itself. Here, it's minor (A>C). Taking the make-up of each, Am = ACE, Cm = CEbG. Making two common notes, the other moving a semitone.

Now, what I don't get is that when something is called a chromatic mediant, it then gets to sound good...

Comment: I guess if a device has a name, it means a few other people liked it too...

Comment: @topomorto - of course! But don't we love to label and pigeon-hole..? Just because we can?

Comment: yes....bad.... people … do that (*glances nervously at my bookshelf where books have painstakingly been arranged in order of colour*)

Comment: @topomorto - I sympathise - I like reading coloured books too...

Comment: Indeed.  I guess we're all human.

Comment: @ScottWallace - at times - most- I try not to be. *To err is human* is a great get-out, though...

Comment: There aren’t two common notes in a chromatic mediant, just one: in this case the C. I don’t think anyone is claiming that it sounds good because it has a label. It has a label because it’s used a lot, but also I’m pretty sure *any* chord connection has a label. Whether it sounds good is a matter of opinion, but surely part of the reason a lot of composers like it is the combination of potentially smooth voice leading and “exotic” chromaticism.

Comment: @PatMuchmore  -thank you. Proving I am human! Corrected. The labelling bit was flippancy.

Comment: @topomorto  depends on the name -- e.g. "Diabolus in musica"